# Perfect Set and Compact Set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, compactness

I am having some difficulty in understanding the difference between **Perfect** and **Compact** sets. More specifically, my problem is rather understanding how **Perfect** sets are different from **Compact sets**, by that I mean, I understand Compact Sets more than Perfect Sets.

I know that for any set, $S$, to be Compact, every sequence of  $S$ has **a subsequence that converges to a point which also lies in** $S$. This is basic definition but is not difference than saying it is Bounded and Closed or Heine Borel Theorem.

Now, the definition of Perfect Set is $P$ is a Perfect Set if $P =P'$ where $P'$ is the set of **Limit Points of** $P$ (WolframAlpha). At other places, I also that a set is Perfect Set if $P$ is closed and accumulation point of $P$. Though, I do not understand this completely, it sounds similar to definition of Compact Sets.

I would appreciate any explanation.

Further, are there are any **non-singleton sets** that are **Compact but Not Perfect**?
How about **Perfect but Non Compact Sets**?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

What you give as the definition of *compact set* is actually the definition of *sequentially compact set*; the two properties are equivalent in metric spaces but not in general. In general a set $K$ in a topological space $X$ is compact if every open cover of $K$ has a finite subcover. This means that if $\mathscr{U}$ is a family of open sets such that $K\subseteq\bigcup\mathscr{U}$ (i.e., $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $K$), then there is a finite subcollection $\mathscr{U}_0\subseteq\mathscr{U}$ such that $K\subseteq\bigcup\mathscr{U}_0$. This no longer looks at all like the definition of a perfect set.

Your definition of *perfect set* is correct: $P$ is perfect if $P=P'$. In Hausdorff spaces (and hence certainly in metric spaces) this is equivalent to saying that $P$ is an infinite closed set with no isolated points.

Even in metric spaces the two are definitely not the same. This can already be seen in the familiar space $\Bbb R$. The set

$$S=\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}\;,$$

for example, is an infinite compact subset of $\Bbb R$ that is certainly not perfect: $S$ consists mostly of isolated points, and $S'=\{0\}$. On the other hand, $\Bbb R$ itself is a perfect subset of $\Bbb R$ that is not compact. The closed ray $[0,\to)$ is another, as is

$$\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z}[2n,2n+1]=\ldots\cup[-4,-3]\cup[-2,-1]\cup[0,1]\cup[2,3]\cup[4,5]\cup\ldots\,\;.$$

What is true in $\Bbb R$ (and in fact in $\Bbb R^n$ for all $n$) is that every uncountable closed set **contains** a perfect subset.

Comment: It may also be worth mentioning that every nonempty perfect set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ contains a compact perfect subset.

Comment: @Trevor Wilson: In fact, from every nonempty perfect set in ${\mathbb R}^n$ you can select continuum many (i.e. $2^{\aleph_{0}}$ many) compact perfect sets that together form a pairwise disjoint collection of sets. Note the contrast with the situation when "perfect set" is replaced with "$n$-dimensional interval", or with "open set", when continuum many becomes at most countably many.