# Uncountable set of $\Bbb R^n$ that does not contain any perfect subset

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

This question is inspired from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/267045/94817):

Every uncountable closed subset of $\Bbb R^n$ contains a perfect subset. [This](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42152353#42152353) chat confirmed me that every uncountable open subset of $\Bbb R^n$ also contains a perfect subset. I tried set of all irrationals, but they also contain a perfect subset.
So my question is :

> Is there any uncountable subset of $\Bbb R^n$ that does not have a perfect subset?

Comment: I think you are also mislead as I was: there are sets that are neither closed nor open.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch "Every uncountable **closed** subset" ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Assuming the axiom of choice**, such sets do indeed exist. This is a straightforward transfinite recursion argument:

- Fix a listing $\{P_\eta: \eta<2^{\aleph_0}\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ the set of perfect subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (crucially, there are only continuum many perfect sets!).
- Now we build a sequence of pairs of sets $(In_\eta, Out_\eta)_{\eta<2^{\aleph_0}}$ as follows:

  - At stage $\eta+1$, we pick some real $r\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus (In_\eta\cup Out_{\eta})$ and some $s\in P_\eta\setminus In_\eta$, and set $$In_{\eta+1}=In_\eta\cup\{r\}, \quad Out_{\eta+1}=Out_\eta\cup\{s\}.$$
  - At a limit stage $\lambda$ we set $$In_\lambda=\bigcup_{\alpha<\lambda} In_\alpha,\quad Out_\lambda=\bigcup_{\alpha<\lambda} Out_\alpha.$$
  - We set $In_0=Out_0=\emptyset$.

Then it's easy to check that $\bigcup_{\eta<2^{\aleph_0}} In_\eta$ is uncountable but contains no perfect subset.

---

However, if the axiom of choice **fails**, this might not work: it is consistent with ZF that every uncountable set has a perfect subset. The most natural way this can happen is if the [Axiom of Determinacy (AD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinacy#Regularity_properties_for_sets_of_reals) holds. This has the drawback that ZF+AD has strictly greater consistency strength than ZF. A more artificial model of ZF + "every uncountable set has a perfect subset" can be constructed merely from the assumption that ZF is consistent; this was done by [Truss](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003484374900151).

---

SEMI-RELATED (but hopefully interesting) CODA:

The necessity of choice suggests that "naturally occurring" sets probably won't be counterexamples. Say that a class $\mathcal{S}$ of sets has the [perfect set property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_set_property) if for all $X\in\mathcal{S}$, either $X$ is countable or $X$ contains a perfect subset; can we prove that "large" classes of sets have the perfect set property?

The answer turns out to be **yes**. ZFC proves that the class of [Borel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set) sets - indeed, the class of [analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_set) sets - has the perfect set property. And while ZFC *doesn't* prove that the class of coanalytic (= complement is analytic) sets has the perfect set property, there are natural axioms which do prove this when added to ZFC - namely, [large cardinal axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_cardinal). In general, the following is a good (informal) heuristic:

> If $X$ is a "nicely definable" set of reals, then - possibly assuming large cardinals - $X$ is either countable or contains a perfect subset.

The study of regularity properties (e.g. perfect set property, [Lebesgue measurability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure), [property of Baire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_of_Baire), ...) of "nicely definable" sets is (one aspect of) [**descriptive set theory**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_set_theory).

Over time, one of the fundamental aspects of descriptive set theory has turned out to be the importance of [determinacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinacy) principles and the central role of large cardinal axioms; [Larson has a nice paper](http://www.users.miamioh.edu/larsonpb/determinacy_cabal.pdf) on the history of this, and for further detail I would recommend [Kanamori's book](http://www.springer.com/de/book/9783540888666).

Comment: Doesn't the last consistency result require an inaccessible? https://mathoverflow.net/q/275216/30186

Comment: @Wojowu That needs the assumption that $\omega_1$ is regular in $V$, which need not be true in ZF alone. I believe the result is correct as I've stated it (though I could be wrong).